# ROS turtlebot3 gazebo camera is black on openCV

Tags: opencv, ros

When i run the following python script to show the turtlebot3 cam on an opencv window, the cam is black, however on rviz the camera seems to be working.

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2, cv_bridge
class Follower:
        def __init__(self):
                self.bridge = cv_bridge.CvBridge()
                cv2.namedWindow("window", 1)
                self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/rgb/image_raw',
                Image, self.image_callback)

        def image_callback(self, msg):
                image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg,desired_encoding='bgr8')
                cv2.imshow("window", image)
                cv2.waitKey(3)
rospy.init_node('follower')
follower = Follower()
rospy.spin()
```